# Error ORA-04073 al crear trigger en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy haciendo un trigger y no soy capaz de encontrar el fallo que estoy teniendo porque no consigo que me compile. Os adjunto el enunciado, las tablas que uso en el trigger y el trigger que tengo creado.

Enunciado:

> El usuario "jefe" creará un trigger que almacenará en la tabla "control_ventas" el libro que haya sido vendido, es decir, cuando se realice un delete en la tabla "libros".

Tabla *LIBROS:*

```
CREATE TABLE LIBROS(
ID number(5) constraint PK_LIBROID primary key.
NOMBRE_LIBRO varchar2(30),
AUTOR_LIBRO varchar2(30),
EDITORIAL varchar2(25),
PRECIO_LIBRO number(4,2)
);
```

Tabla *CONTROL_VENTAS*:

```
create table CONTROL_VENTAS(
USUARIO varchar2(25),
FECHA date,
ID_LIBROS number(5),
PRECIO number(4,2)
);
```

Trigger que tengo creado:

```
create or replace TRIGGER LIBROS_VENTAS
after delete of PRECIO_LIBRO on LIBROS FOR EACH ROW when(OLD.PRECIO_LIBRO > NEW.PRECIO_LIBRO)

BEGIN
  insert into CONTROL_VENTAS
  values(
        USER,
        SYSDATE,
        :OLD.ID,
        :OLD.PRECIO_LIBRO
        );
END;
/
```

Error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La sintaxis `OF <columna>` sólo aplica para `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Sal he quitado el of y me hace el trigger pero con warnings